# Why Pyspark is turning off my Computer with heavy computation?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am running this script:

```
import pyspark
import random

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")

num_samples = 100000000

def inside(p):     
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()
pi = 4 * count / num_samples
print(pi)
sc.stop()
```

And it's working without any issues.

If I increase the `num_samples` variable to `1000000000` for example, after like 2 seconds my computer shutdown completely.

cpu: amd 5950x
64gb RAM
gpu: RTX 3070 TI

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe your power supply or cooling isn't enough for the rest of your hardware.

Comment: I am using a Corsair CV750.  Should Iget some log or something to point out the exact reason?

Comment: This is a hardware problem; no computation should be able to do this to properly working hardware.  As such it is off topic for Stack Overflow, but could be taken instead to https://superuser.com.